# Escape from Alcatraz: SqlAnywhere to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, migration, syntax, sybase-sql-anywhere

Is there a migration tool that actually works for SAP SqlAnywhere 17 to MSSQL (any recent version)?

Searching for "sqlanywhere mssql migration" yields a variety of hits including SQL Server Migration Assistance (SSMA) but all of the tools I have tried — various free and some trials of commercial offerings — all failed to handle the following test (assume T is a real table with columns A and B):

```
SELECT A, B + 'X' AS B1 FROM T GROUP BY B1
```

SqlAnywhere permits this but on MSSQL the symbol `B1` is not in scope in the `GROUP BY` clause, and the query must be transformed as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT A, B + 'X' AS B1 FROM T) AS T1 GROUP BY B1
```

I wasn't even able to test SSMA. It is available for a range of platforms including Sybase ASE but is *not* compatible with the database formerly known as Sybase SqlAnywhere and now titled SAP SqlAnywhere. I've tried this, and it is not interested in using my SqlAnywhere ODBC drivers.

If there isn't an out of the box migration tool then is there anything that can transform syntax? In some ways this would be even more helpful than a migration tool because our applications are riddled with queries that exhibit this particular incompatibility. I seriously considered writing a transformation myself but quickly realised that SQL syntax is hideously complex and idiosyncratic.

Comment: This will likely be closed as it's a shopping list question, however, I suggest you reach out to Microsoft Directly in this case.  If you have an MSDN license, you should be able to take advantage of their [Concierge Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/vs-concierge-chat) and see if they have any similar tools available.  They may not, but that'll likely be your best bet.

Comment: As it happens I think I do have what passes for an MSDN licence in these days of learn.microsoft.com -- a Visual Studio subscription, so I'll give that a whirl. But if questions like this aren't permitted how are people expected to deal with this kind of situation? This isn't _I'm too lazy to run a search for "SqlAnywhere mssql migration tool", land on the SSMA site, read it and weep, then download it and try anyway._

Comment: Concierge chat said my question was too technical and referred me to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/home

Comment: _Shopping List_ questions are not permitted because after some time it's pretty much guaranteed that new products will come out that would be relevant to this question, but the list that may be accepted now may not even be relevant later down the road.  These rules are not my creation, but I can say that the general approach of all SE sites is to keep the Q&A relevant regardless if you come across the answer from today or 5 years ago.  This sort of restriction helps to ensure that.

Comment: Yes, they've been saying that to me since 2008, and I've been replying that this in software development permanence of relevance is fine for a museum and absurd for a dev resource.